# Using YUM or installing APT on CentOS

Tags: centos, rpm, yum

I am having trouble with a centOS machine I am using. I need some packages, including *john the ripper*, but **`yum`** cannot find the packages.

When I type `sudo yum install john`, I get back the *nothing to do* message. Is there a way to improve the searched locations to install **`john`** or is it possible to install APT on CentOS machines? I know it isn't exactly supported but I am at a loss and do not have the hours necessary to install from source and rpms :(

Answer (score 1):

John the Ripper is available from [RPMForge](http://rpmrepo.org/RPMforge), and the package name is `john`.  As you mentioned in an answer, Snort is also available in RPMForge as `snort-rep`.  It doesn't look like it has Nessus, but it has something called `perl-Net-Nessus-XMLRPC`.

I found `nessus` on [ATRPMs](http://atrpms.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the yum repository to some better repository out there you can also try rpmfusion. http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration/

Comment: The distribution's repository is to be used in strong preference, then EPEL (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux, a set of packages maintained specifically for RHEL by the Fedora project), and then go looking elsewhere. There is _no_ guarantee that random packages installed from third parties don't mess up your system (RPMfusion is rather careful in this, I should add).